# Coding a small file bundler for HTML/JS/CSS

Tags: java, powershell, web, bundler

So my project has a lot of small "widget" like components with their own CSS and JS.
What I need is a sort of automatism to "bundle" up the css and js of all the components into a single file with a press of a button (or cmd expression).

Something like this: `bundleMeFiles.exe -header -footer -widget1`
or if all: `bundleMeFiles.exe -all`.

I know there are tools and a lot of stuff that does that in a great scale but I'm also a DIY guy so I like doing my own stuff because it makes me improve.

My first guess is Powershell or even Java to build a fancy UI but any tips would be welcome.

Comment: It sounds like you want a tool like webpack or browserify. However, open requests for a tool are off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in java by using the [commons-io library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File result = new File("C:/temp/result.txt");
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(result);
    Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(
            new File("C:/temp/dir"),
            new RegexFileFilter("^(.*?)"),
            DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY
    );
    for(File f: files){
        //path to file surrounded by ===
        IOUtils.writeLines(
                Arrays.asList("===", f.getAbsolutePath(), "==="),
                "\r\n",
                os,
                Charset.defaultCharset());
        //file contents
        IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(f), os);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I will do this in java, simple language and does the job well! Thanks for the code saved me some research.